# How to set password for PostgreSQL database with a script?

Tags: postgresql, linux, scripting

In a bash script I'm writing, I need to create a database and set a password that is generated automatically by my script.

The problem is I can't find a way to set up the password without user interaction.

I need something like this:

```
$ createdb mydb -p $(cat password_file)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11039499/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736231/330315

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: in the case that you're thinking of a password assigned to the database itself, postgres doesn't have this. Passwords are assigned to database users which are separately granted the permission to connect to databases.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html):

> `createdb` is a wrapper around the SQL command `CREATE DATABASE`.
>   There is no effective difference between creating databases via this
>   utility and via other methods for accessing the server.

This means that you can write a script which issues a command like

```
psql -f createdb.sql -v passwd=$passwd -v user=$user
```

Where `createdb.sql` contains something like

```
CREATE ROLE :user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD :passwd;
CREATE DATABASE mydb OWNER :user;
GRANT {some privileges on the newly created database and/or its objects};
```

This means that you will have a user for every database created.

(At the same time I have a mild suspicion that your problem is what riouj answered.)

Comment: old but good: I've been looking for this forever!

Answer (score 3):

In order to connect to your PostgreSQL instance and run the `createdb` script, which is a client, you can use a password file. This file is generally located at `~/.pgpass` and must contain theses information :

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

If you want to use a different path for your password file, you can set the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable.

For security concerns, you can change its rights :

```
chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
```

If you don't want `createdb` to prompt you for any password, you can use the -w switch (or --no-password) and use the password file.

You can take a look at the documentation for these features :

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createdb.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html